# How can i find frozen_inference_graph.pb input and output node?

Tags: tensorflow, movidius

i have already trained a model by ssd inception v2 model and use "export_inference_graph.py" to generated the frozen_inference_graph.pb

i tried to use below command to generated the model then try to use mvNCCompiler to convert it to movidius graph

```
python3 /home/chanchihang/Special_Topic/models/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py 
--input_type image_tensor 
--pipeline_config_path /home/chanchihang/Special_Topic/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config 
--trained_checkpoint_prefix /home/chanchihang/Special_Topic/models/research/inceptionV2_Training/model.ckpt-20000 
--output_directory /home/chanchihang/Special_Topic/models/research/inceptionV2_Training/
```

then i tried to convert model.ckpt.meta by mvNCCompiler to movidius graph and get error below

```
mvNCCompile model.ckpt.meta -in=image_tensor -on=detection_scores -is 224 224 -o test.graph


Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/bin/mvNCCompile", line 118, in <module>
    create_graph(args.network, args.inputnode, args.outputnode, args.outfile, args.nshaves, args.inputsize, args.weights)
  File "/usr/local/bin/mvNCCompile", line 104, in create_graph
    net = parse_tensor(args, myriad_config)
  File "/usr/local/bin/ncsdk/Controllers/TensorFlowParser.py", line 259, in parse_tensor
    input_data = np.random.uniform(0, 1, shape)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 961, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.uniform
  File "common.pyx", line 557, in numpy.random.common.cont
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: You will need to visualize the graph in TensorBoard. Or you may find the names in the GitHub repo

Comment: i find the node about input and output but it still error like above
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer